# RequireJS/AMD and globally available values

Tags: requirejs, amd

I am using RequireJS/AMD to break up my JS app.  One of my modules is an "environment" module that does nothing more than make a request (asynchronously) and then store the returned data.  This environment module is a dependency for practically every other module in my app.

My issue is that I need this environment information available immediately. Is there a way I can ensure that my asynchronous request has completed and that my variables are set correctly before the environment module returns?

**environment.js**

```
define(["./opui"], function(opui){

    var environment = {
            jsonpath: null,
            imgpath: null,
            platform: null
    }; 

    //request environment data asynchronously
    getEnvironment();

    //callback that sets environment data
    setEnvironment();

    return environment;

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Having to worry about initialisation order often means that the design is flawed; that's exactly what RequireJS is there for.

Use the [text plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/text)† in every module that needs this `environment` data:

```
define(['dep1', 'dep2', 'text!./environment'],
  function (dep1, dep2, environmentJsonString) {
    var environment = JSON.parse(environmentJsonString);
    dep1.foo(environment.platform);
});
```

Where `./environment` is the URL of the server-side call that returns the data as JSON, e.g.:

```
{ "jsonpath": "...",
  "imgpath": "...",
  "platform": "..." }
```

This makes retrieving data during app's startup a dependency so RequireJS will take care of waiting for the async AJAX call to `./environment` to return.

Keep in mind that all modules will share the same mutable instance. Also, don't forget to set `inlineText: false` in `r.js`'s build config to avoid inlining that JSON string during the optimisation process.

† *there's a JSON plugin that handles text->JSON parsing but for some reason it didn't work for me.*